# About the participle of Absolute construction

Tags: participles, absolute-construction

Is there any difference in meaning between these two sentences?

> 1. My car **breaking** down, I had to take a taxi to work.

> 2. My car **having broken** down, I had to take a taxi to work.

Comment: The first one sounds very formal and old-fashioned.

Comment: It's something you might write in a memoir; it's not at all colloquial English.

Comment: @JohnLawler, Prof, what about the expression  ‘’ As my car had broken down, I had to take a taxi to work" ?  In colloquial English, compared with the absolute phrase, an adverbial clause is strongly preferred, right?

Comment: Use _since_ instead of _as_; that's bookish. Or you could just resort to two short sentences - _My car broke down. I had to take a taxi to work_. Anybody can put two and two together without needing a guiding word like _since_.

Comment: @JohnLawler, Noted with thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [perfect aspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_(grammar)) (almost always indicated by "to have" + past participle, as in sentence #2) implies an earlier time. Because your car presumably broke down before you had to take a taxi, sentence #2 is better. (If both events happened at the same time, then sentence #1 would be appropriate. That seems unlikely.)